# String Number in jqgrid select

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        gridComplete: function () {
        var ids = jQuery("#grdProgramsEnrolled").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var cl = ids[i];
            var rowId = $("#grdProgramsEnrolled").getRowData(cl)
            var PUIC = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_hfldUIC").val();
            be = "<a href='#'>Select</a >";
            be = "<a href='#' onclick='GetEnrollmentByCIP(" + rowId['CIP'] + ")'>Select</a >";
            jQuery("#grdProgramsEnrolled").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { ab: be });
        }   // end of for loop
```

In the rowID['CIP'] the CIP can have a value like 01.0000 or 19.0000 or 12.9999. If the value is 12.9999 my GetEnrollmentByCIP function will see the passed value as 12.9999. If it is 19.0000 the function will see the passed value as 19. If it is 01.0000 the function will not see any passed value. How do I code the 'GetEnrollmentByCIP(" + rowId['CIP'] + ") so that it will pass the value as the whole string like 01.0000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the variable as a string, not a number:

```
be = "<a href='#' onclick='GetEnrollmentByCIP(\"" + rowId['CIP'] + \"")'>Select</a >";
//                                             ^escaped doublequotes^
```

Comment: I tried that already but it will give me a "Select>Select" in my grid and will still not pass the value correctly

Comment: so I tried the following                                          be = "<a href='#'>Programs</a >";
da = "\"" + rowId['CIP'] + "\"";
be = "<a href='#' onclick='GetEnrollmentByCIP(" + da + ")'>Programs</a>";                                                this would pass a string value to the function but the select column had Programs listed 2 times in it.

Comment: because you have two anchor tags with "Programs" as the text... ?

Comment: so I copmmented out the first line and left only the line as you described above.                                                                     //be = "<a href='#'>Select</a >";
       be = "<a href='#' onclick='GetEnrollmentByCIP(\"" + rowId['CIP'] + "\")'>Select</a >";  and it still shows in my colums as Select">Select. Why is that? Whata do I need to do?